# Remove a word from a string

Tags: javascript, string

i want to remove a particular #keyword from a string. i dont know its position or anything.
can i use javascript to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "particular #keyword";
str.replace("keyword", "new");
alert(str); //-> "particular #new"
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can, using [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/Replace) method

Comment: To clarify that is not a JavaScript function, not jQuery dependent.

Comment: @durilai, you mean that **is a** JavaScript function? :P