# Remove from String (from Array) in Javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove a word from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533807/remove-a-word-from-a-string)

I have a simple string `var mystr = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"`, and I have an array `var lipsums = new Array("dolor","consectetur","elit");` Now, I want a simple function which will remove any same word in the string.

So, in the above example, it should remove the words "dolor", "consectetur", and "elit" and my string `mystr` should be `"Lorem ipsum sit amet, adipiscing"`

This script should be in Javascript (no jQuery). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which part don't you know how to do? Iterate the Array? Manipulate the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over the array of words to remove, removing all occurances via split/join:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lipsums.length; i++) {
    mystr = mystr.split(lipsums[i]).join('');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Rgzd/

You may also want to clean up your whitespace afterwards, which you can do with a regex:

```
// Note: don't do this in the loop!
mystr = mystr.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Rgzd/1/

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
for(i=0; i<lipsums.length; i++) {
   mystr = mystr.replace(new RegExp(lipsums[i],"g"), "");
}
```

Add this AFTER the loop to remove double white space's:

```
mystr = mystr.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ');
```

Comment: Don't forget to collapse the whitespace, which you now have extra.

Comment: Also, you must return it to the variable `mystr` since `.replace()` does not mutate the string.

Comment: What if you have multiple "dolor, consectetur, ..." in the string? The replace function will only replace the first occurrence...

Comment: This would be better `mystr.replace(new RegExp(lipsums[i],"g"),'');` (or gi for case insensitive)